# Custom camera aspect ratio is incorrect

Tags: android, camera, android-4.4-kitkat, aspect-ratio

I built a custom camera activity in my Android app and render the camera preview in a FrameLayout.  I'm running into issues, though, with devices that run KitKat - the aspect ratio of the camera preview appears to be incorrect (you can see things look squashed vertically with the image on the left). When I take a photo, though, the aspect ratio of the saved image is correct (which you can see with the image on the right).

[image]

**How can I fix this aspect ratio issue?**

Here is how I check whether the device is running KitKat, and then I apply the fullscreen layout:

```
// put the views behind the navigation bar
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
        Log.d(TAG, "adjusting to account for navigation bar");
          getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN );
}
```

This is what I have for setting the camera preview size:

```
private void setHolderParameters() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setting camera layout parameters");
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    Size mPreviewSize = CameraPreview.getOptimalPreviewSize(camera
            .getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes(), width, height);

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
    parameters.set("orientation", "portrait"); // default orientation to
                                               // portrait
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
}
```

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/gallery_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
         >

        <com.example.helperClass.PictureHorizontalLayout
            android:id="@+id/mygallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" >
        </com.example.helperClass.PictureHorizontalLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camerapreview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black" 
        />   

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_holder_customized_cam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#838B8B"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="0.9"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/gallery_customized_camera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add"
            android:maxWidth="75dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_picture" >

            <!-- android:background="@drawable/custom_button_blue" -->

        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/shutter_customized_camera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_blue"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add"
            android:maxWidth="75dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" >
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/video_customized_camera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add"
            android:maxWidth="75dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_video" >

            <!-- android:background="@drawable/custom_button_blue" -->

        </ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/camera_timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_holder_customized_cam"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/no_time"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`width` and `height` that you feed to `CameraPreview.getOptimalPreviewSize()` should be calculated based on the current screen layout, and take into account all the elements (e.g. navigation bar) that the system displays on the screen, and the elements (e.g. `button_holder_customized_cam`) that your app logic decides to display.

With the former, you have limited control (e.g. switch to fullscreen layout); with the latter, you can tune their size to fill the gap around the preview surface (with correct aspect ratio).

It's OK in my understanding to leave some margins filled with a non-intrusive background color, if necessary. You can overlay the preview surface with other views, which is visually equivalent to cropping the preview image. Actually, it is technically possible (but not easy) to crop the preview image itself.

Comment: thanks for the advice.  the strange thing is that I hid both the status bar and the navigation bar to check whether the aspect ratio was still off, and it was still slightly squashed, even when the camera preview takes up the entire screen.  So I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Typically, cameras support 4:3 or 16:9 previews; the physical screens often are a bit taller, to have a standard 16:9 area _above_ the navigation bar.

Comment: The width and height of the FrameLayout containing the camera preview is set to wrap_contents, so I thought that it wouldn't stretch the preview, even if the physical screen is not exactly 16:9.  How do you suggest preventing the stretching?

Comment: I usually use `match_parent` for the preview SurfaceView, but this does not make big difference because I override [onMeasure()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int,%20int)) and [set measured dimensions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setMeasuredDimension(int,%20int)) to fit the expected aspect ratio.